# What is the difference between "decorator design" and "template design" in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I've seen an example of **template design**, and its instructions is:

> Applicable to situations where there is a similar algorithm structure but certain steps may vary.
>
> Commonly used in software development to implement operations with similar workflows but differing details.

However, I think this example(as following) can also use "**decorator design**".

It seems that template design and decorator can achieve the same result.

I want to understand the application of template design, but the examples or instructions on the web didn't make it clear to me.

Who can tell me the difference between template and decorator?

### Template Design

```py
def dots_style(msg):
    msg = msg.capitalize()
    msg = '.' * 10 + msg + '.' * 10
    return msg


def admire_style(msg):
    msg = msg.upper()
    return '!'.join(msg)


def generate_banner(msg, style=dots_style):
    print('-- start of banner --')
    print(style(msg))
    print('-- end of banner --\n\n')


def main():
    msg = 'happy coding'
    [generate_banner(msg, style) for style in (dots_style, admire_style)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Result

```
-- start of banner --
..........Happy coding..........
-- end of banner --


-- start of banner --
H!A!P!P!Y! !C!O!D!I!N!G
-- end of banner --
```

### Decorator Design

```py
from functools import wraps


def generate_banner(style):
    @wraps(style)
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        print('-- start of banner --')
        print(style(*arg, **kwargs))
        print('-- end of banner --\n\n')

    return wrapper


@generate_banner
def dots_style(msg):
    msg = msg.capitalize()
    msg = '.' * 10 + msg + '.' * 10
    return msg


@generate_banner
def admire_style(msg):
    msg = msg.upper()
    return '!'.join(msg)


def main():
    msg = 'happy coding'
    dots_style(msg)
    admire_style(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Results

```
-- start of banner --
..........Happy coding..........
-- end of banner --


-- start of banner --
H!A!P!P!Y! !C!O!D!I!N!G
-- end of banner --
```

Comment: The decorator-using code is already more complex, and either way, you can achieve both of these with just function composition: `admire_banner = lambda msg: add_banner_lines(admire_style(msg))` (assuming `add_banner_lines` is a thing)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the term **template design** accurately?

Comment: @AKX you're right. But I just want to understand the template design can use for what.

Comment: @Timus Accutually I'm not, I'm the first contact and learning desgin pattern. And the example of template design  is a reference to the explanation on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator design pattern adds functionality to an object / function dynamically, while the template design pattern defines the skeleton of an algorithm with customizable steps in subclasses.

*In your example*
The template design approach allows you to define different styles for generating banners while keeping the overall structure intact. You can choose which style to use by passing it as a parameter to the **generate_banner** function. On the other hand, the decorator design approach allows you to dynamically add the banner functionality to different styles by using the **generate_banner** decorator.